# Python: SSLError using requests for surveymonkey.com

Tags: python, ssl, openssl

Python Version: Python 2.7.6

OS: OSX 10.10.3

I'm trying to [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)   "https://www.surveymonkey.com/"

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get('https://www.surveymonkey.com/')
```

but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jasony/Documents/python/scripts2/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jasony/Documents/python/scripts2/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jasony/Documents/python/scripts2/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/jasony/Documents/python/scripts2/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jasony/Documents/python/scripts2/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 431, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno bad handshake] [('SSL routines', 'SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')]
```

I don't get the same error with "https://www.google.com"

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get('https://www.google.com')
<Response [200]>
```

Does this mean there is an issue with surveymonkey's ssl?

Python Version: 2.7.10

```
>>> requests.get('https://www.surveymonkey.com/mp/legal/which-terms-apply')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jasony/Documents/python/scripts2/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jasony/Documents/python/scripts2/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jasony/Documents/python/scripts2/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/jasony/Documents/python/scripts2/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jasony/Documents/python/scripts2/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 431, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)
```

**Update**:
I've tried Python 2.7.6, Python 2.7.9, Python 2.7.10

with OS: OSX 10.10.3 with OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015. Requests versions 2.4.3, 2.5.3, 2.7.0.

I've tried to [configure the ssl protocol.](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#example-specific-ssl-version%20'adapting%20the%20SSL%20protocal') Python 2.7.10 / Requests 2.7.0 The following is the code:

```
import ssl
import requests

from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager


class Ssl3HttpAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    """"Transport adapter" that allows us to use SSLv3."""

    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                       maxsize=maxsize,
                                       block=block,
                                       ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3)

s = requests.Session()
s.mount('https://', Ssl3HttpAdapter())
url = 'https://www.surveymonkey.com/'
print s.get(url)
```

I still get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "redirect.py", line 29, in <module>
    print s.get(url)
  File "/Users/jasony/Documents/python/scripts2/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 469, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jasony/Documents/python/scripts2/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 457, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/jasony/Documents/python/scripts2/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 569, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jasony/Documents/python/scripts2/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 420, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)
```

Comment: are you sure? Works fine for me on python3 and python2

Comment: It's an issue with Python < 2.7.9 IIRC, either compile your Python with new SSL module or upgrade to Python 2.7.9.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I get the same error on Python 2.7.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this on my machine (Py 3.4.2/2.7.9, requests 2.4.3, requests 2.7.0, OpenSSL 1.0.1k, Debian Jessie). I have seen similar messages on some machines with old OpenSSL versions.

You might try upgrading your Python/OpenSSL (old versions of Python ship with old OpenSSL versions) or digging deeper by testing using the OpenSSL command line tool and varying the options to dig deeper. It might be helpful to tell us on which OS and which Python version you are on.

```
openssl s_client -connect www.surveymonkey.com:443
```

See SSL Labs to get the supported TLS versions and ciphers of the server in a human-friendly format.
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.surveymonkey.com

As suggested you might try to force a certain TLS version or change the list of supported ciphers. It seems like there is not nice way to influence the ciphers via the API as far as I know.

Since it works for some people and does not for others, we might want to compare the default ciphers used in different versions. Changing it to ALL should will likely make it work, but is not very secure, so one should find out which restriction is the culprit. The SSL Labs website helps you with that.

See the code below on how to change the default chiphers list:

```
import requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_
print(requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS)
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'ALL'
```

Comment: Thanks for the SSLtest.
My opsnssl version is 'OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015'
Requests version 2.7.0
surveymonkey supports TLS

Comment: Rondom has it right. Basically, you either need to update python to make sure urllib3 is installed, or [configure the ssl protocol yourself](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#example-specific-ssl-version).

Comment: Updated my answer - what os are you on?

Comment: I am on Debian Linux Jessie. Currently cannot test it myself, but in the SSLAdapter you used SSLv3 which cannot work since surveymonkey does not support it. Try using ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1

Comment: You might try to play with the list of supported ciphers. It seems like there is not nice way to influence this via the API as far as I know. Here is what works for me on Py 2.7. PLEASE don't just use ALL, let's instead find out what the actual problem is and why it works for some people and not for others. It might make sense to compare the default ciphers of those different people.

    import requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_
    print(requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS)
    requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'ALL'

Answer (score 0):

Two methods:

1. `import requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_` `requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'ALL'`
2. `$ pip install requests[security]`

Comment: Need to correct the single quotation mark before 'ALL'.